# Alternatives to ppl

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, portability, parallel-processing

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531845/is-it-possible-to-convert-my-loop-into-parallel-for-fnc-invocation) I've asked, I touched the parallel_for subject from ppl.h provided by Microsoft.
But shortly after I've realized that by using it one makes his application unportable (if I'm right it is specific to Microsoft (the ppl.h header)).
In my opinion this breaks very important aspect of programming in C++ - portability, and I'm just not prepare to do it.
So my questions are:
1. Am I right in saying that using parallel_for from ppl makes your code unportable (by unportable I mean that it cannot be compiled by other compiler than the one from MS)
2. Am I right in saying that if on later stage I want to provide UI (done in Qt) for the application I'm working on at the momment, using parallel_for in my code will be an obstruction which would mean that either I'll replace parallel_for with some other (portable) alternative or I won't be able to do UI in Qt and core in VS?
3. What are the (portable) alternatives to ppl?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may want to consider Intel's [Thread Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/). Unlike OpenMP, TBB actually *uses* C++, rather than simply compiling under a C++ compiler (ie: being a C library that can compile as C++). It has many of the things you see in PPL, but it is cross-platform.

There is also Boost.Thread, which is C++ (though not quite as direct as TBB is), and it is cross-platform.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Nicol, is there anything "really special" about ppl that would made one to use it over i.e. TBB, sacrificing portability?

Comment: OpenMP isn't a library, it's foremost a compiler extension. It adds parallelism *in the language*.

Comment: @smallB, On VC10 yes, it helps in debugging. VC10 shows Parallel tasks and parallel stacks, which is well integrated with ConcRT.

Comment: If you are interested in TBB have a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7527541/2690296

Answer (score 6):

The people working on the [Casablanca](http://casablanca.codeplex.com/) project have been making a portable version of PPL, called PPLX. It's licensed under an [Apache 2.0](http://casablanca.codeplex.com/license) license.

They previously have said they are working closely together with the PPL team to keep both versions in sync feature and bugfix wise (see last post in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/casablanca/thread/605c25c9-1184-40cd-acc2-93ada1cc5dd6)).

Comment: PPLX is focused on support for tasks.  It doesn't have support for parallel_for or anything matched by parallel_* for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you use PPL or TBB (or HPX) ... something very similar is going to be standardised. For instance see: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4411.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> Am I right in saying that using
>   parallel_for from ppl makes your code
>   unportable (by unportable I mean that
>   it cannot be compiled by other
>   compiler than the one from MS)

Unportable if you switch the platform itself. May be portable on Windows, if you want to use other compilers. But know that PPL is part of Concurrency Runtime, which is placed in MSVCRT100.DLL, and you need to link to this (or statically link, without needing DLL at runtime). I am not sure how this can be done with other compilers/linkers, but I do believe it is doable.

> Am I right in saying that if on later
>   stage I want to provide UI (done in
>   Qt) for the application I'm working on
>   at the momment, using parallel_for in
>   my code will be an obstruction which
>   would mean that either I'll replace
>   parallel_for with some other
>   (portable) alternative or I won't be
>   able to do UI in Qt and core in VS

You can write your core-framework in using PPL/VC++, and other GUI counterpart in QT/other-compiler. For this just make a DLL which would use PPL, and your GUI application would use the DLL. I do believe you understand what I mean here. This also reduces burden from your head about portability (on Windows).

1. What are the (portable) alternatives to ppl?

Many, but I prefer using PPL on Windows/VC++. You may consider using Intel's TBB. OpenMP is troublesome, and doesn't give advantages as compared to TBB/ConcRT