# Is Microsoft Visual C++ tied to windows platform?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to learn C++ and I want to know if using Microsoft VC++ will tie me to Windows. I specially need my project to also run on Mac. My projects are all Class libraries and have no dependency to UI. They are just calculations or file/network IO.

I really like working in Visual Studio and Microsoft way overall. So my priority is to go VC++ unless it makes painful to build cross platform apps for Windows and Mac. I mean at the compiler, libraries and language level. I don't want my parallel app to fall apart on certain platforms.

Comment: Do you mean the Visual Studio IDE or the actual compiler/linker? You can use the IDE for cross-platform development, or any other IDE, but it's some work to get it up and running. Besides, if you want to use any OSX specific library or framework you're out of luck if you want to program in C++ as you need to develop on an actual OSX system using Xcode for full access to the OSX specific frameworks.

Comment: Microsoft has its own compiler for C++ (MSVC), LINUX got GCC and CLANG (which also exist in WINDOWS), and MAC also got them, the only thing I'd worry about is standard compliance, as long as you are writing with compliance to the standard, it will build normally, if you slip into MSVC way, it may not build, as they all differe a little ins some approaches.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I want to use Visual Studio on my PC but the project has to work on PC and Mac. It has calculation, multithreading and file and network I/O and I hope they can be done a cross-platform way.

Comment: @Kiloreux Thanks. Can you suggest a book to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personnaly use Visual Studio to build my code on Windows and other compilers to build the same code on other platforms (Mac, Linux, Android...).

To be sure you don't get locked with Windows, make sure (at least, it's not exhaustive):

- You don't use any win32 API (prefer cross plateforme libraries like [boost](http://www.boost.org/) for instance for network, file system access...)
- You don't use 3rd party libraries only available for Windows
- Don't use CString, or anyother Microsoft class. Prefer STL.
- Be careful with file system case sensitiveness too! (`#include "Foo.h"` while file is "foo.h" on disk will work on PC, not under Mac/Linux). Prefer naming ALL your files in lower case.
- ...

You may want to have a look at [CMake](https://cmake.org/). This tool can help you generating compilation project file for the same source to be compiled on different plateform. Then, you can generate vcproj/sln files to compile your code with [Visual Studio](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/generator/Visual%20Studio%2012%202013.html) on Windows, [MakeFile(s)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/generator/Unix%20Makefiles.html) to compile it under Linux and [XCode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/generator/Xcode.html) project files to compile it under MacOS. If somewone wants to compile you code under Windows with another compiler than Microsoft, it's also possible!

Also note that recent version of VS (2015) propose to compile for other targets that Windows (at least Android). But never tried that.

Comment: I saw on wikipedia that GCC can compile on Windows, Mac and PC. Isn't that enough or CMake does something else?

Comment: @mortezakhosravi: CMake will help you generating Makefile for GCC. You'll maintain CMakeLists.txt files instead of Makefiles. This will help you move from one compiler to another in the end.

Comment: @mortezakhosravi: You're mixing two levels of build tools. CMake and also Make are tools which figure out which files should be sent to GCC or Clang for compilation. With Visual Studio, the IDE hides the details, but there too the MSBuild engine decides what files should be compiled.

Comment: @MSalters Now I got the picture. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The compiler itself is pretty standard confroming by know (if you turn off the extensions) and more importantly, you can use the clang frontend (which is the default compiler on Mac) directly from within VS2015, so it is definitvely **possible** to write cross-platform code in VS (although it's certainly easier to use Windows specific constructs than it where if you'd use e.g. cygwin).

However, the windows API for network I/O is different from the one for Mac, so you should probably use a corssplatform library like boost asio for that.

As far as multithreading is concerned, you can do it in a standard and portable manner using the standard library's functions, classes and synchronization primitives, but the past has shown that they are often not the most efficient way to go. However, in most situations you'll want to use a more highlevel library for parallel programming anyway. The default on Windows is the PPL which is - I believe - not cross-platform, but there are other [libraries you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533446/alternatives-to-ppl)

Finally, you can use VS to remotely build your applications on Mac or Linux PCs using their local compilers and libraries. However, I don'T know, how well that works in practice.